# Does Swagger also work with Jersey 2.x?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0, swagger

What I want to do is to add Swagger to my REST Api based on Jersey 2.x.

But it seems Swagger for Jersey is based on Jersey 1.x.
When I added the Swagger dependencies in Maven I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:304)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:285)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.<init>(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:331)
  at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.java:119)
```

I think this is because

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jersey-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

has dependency to

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.13</version>
</dependency>
```

And this is in conflict to the Jersey 2.x my application is using.
Is there a Swagger integration for Jersey 2.x available?

Any ideas how to solve my problem otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following dependency instead:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.10</version>
</dependency>
```

And that should solve your problem. We're going to release a new tutorial on how to integrate with jersey/jersey2 soon.

Comment: Have you published your new tutorial yet ? Could you please share a link ?

Comment: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup

Comment: Ron, I followed the steps from the tutorial [Swagger Core Jersey 2.X Project Setup](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup) but do not see anything when I type `http://localhost:8080/myapp/v1/api` in the URL (in fact I get a HTTP Status 404 - Not Found error). Not sure what am I missing. However, I see some stuff printed on the page when I type `http://localhost:8080/myapp/v1/api-docs` specifically: `{"apiVersion":"1.0.0","swaggerVersion":"1.2"}`

Comment: You probably missed a step or two in the tutorial. However, we won't be able to cover it in comments. I'd suggest writing a question with the full details to our mailing list.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The question has been wrote in the mailing list? In case can you please add a link here?

Comment: Have you followed the guide? Step by step?

Comment: I think so :). I can open a new question in SO or in the mailing list if necessary.

Comment: Would be better in the mailing list. Easier to go back and forth.

Comment: Opened: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/swagger-swaggersocket/BV3Qha91vxI

Comment: @Rentonie - context helps. 2.0 of what?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid `swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10` in Ron's answer is outdated.

Per https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5, here is an updated dependency to use (as of Feb 2016):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```